# How to band-pass filter data in frequency domain?

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform, signal-processing

Let's say I have some (complex) data in the frequency domain, so essentially I have an array of frequency values and a corresponding array of data. I want to apply a band-pass filter to this data (such as a Butterworth) to zero out the data at high and low frequencies. How can I do this in the frequency domain (without going into the time domain at all)?

I know that there is probably some function to multiply my data by, since multiplication in the frequency domain is equivalent to convolution in the time domain. I know that I can't impose a brick-wall filter of just setting the appropriate data to zero, since that would be equivalent to convolving time-domain data with a sinc function. So what would the appropriate function or procedure be to accomplish band-pass filtering in the frequency domain?

Comment: First off, is this data discrete or continuous in the time domain? Second, what is wrong with effectively convolving the original data with a sinc?

Comment: The data is discrete in the time domain. I suppose I could convolve with a sinc, but I've been told that would introduce ringing (which may not be good for the physical situation I'm modeling). I'm looking for something "cleaner", even if more complicated.

Comment: You'll have to give more detail as to what is acceptable and what isn't. Perhaps describe your situation, because there are quite literally an infinite number of things you could try and "cleaner" is too vague a term to narrow that down.

Comment: A standard method of bandlimiting is by zeroing the corresponding frequency bins (if your time data is real, make sure you zero the conjugate frequency so that when you apply the IFFT your signal doesn't gain a complex part). This process of zeroing frequency coefficients is viewed as a projection onto a vector subspace; I have never heard this process described as convolution with a sinc function.

Comment: You should ask this on dsp.stackexchange.com

Comment: If you're not going back to the time domain at all, then what do you care that a brickwall filter will cause aliasing in the time domain?  If you actually are going back to the time domain with your filtered data, then a common approach is to use a filter that is windowed (aka weighted and truncated) sinc function in the time domain.  Such a windowed sinc is going to give you a filter in the frequency domain for which you'll need to specify pass band ripple, transition band width, maximum sidelobe levels, etc.  IOW you need to specify a filter design of what acceptable before anyone can help.